# clang (c++) can't find name within specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following code compiles with gcc (g++) but complains with clang (c++).

I was expecting the line `n1::generic(*it);` to look for a `my_traits<bool>` (or `my_traits<const bool>`) specialization but, it seems to be looking for the name `specific` within the `vector` (const?) from within that same specialization.

Also, this is specific to bool. Other types like int work fine. (I tried adding a `my_traits<vector<bool> >` (and also const bool) specialization but it didn't help).

```
#include <vector>

namespace n1 {

    template <class T> struct my_traits { };

    template <> struct my_traits<bool> {
        static void specific(bool b) { }
    };

    template <> struct my_traits<int> {
        static void specific(int b) { }
    };

    template <typename T> void generic(const T& t)
    {
        my_traits<T>::specific(t);
    }

    template <typename T> struct my_traits<std::vector<T> > {
        static void specific(const std::vector<T>& b)
        {
            if (! b.empty()) {
                for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = b.begin();
                        it != b.end(); ++it) {
                    n1::generic(*it);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

namespace n2 {
    struct ArrayOfBoolean {
        std::vector<bool> values;
    };

    struct ArrayOfInt {
        std::vector<int> values;
    };
}

namespace n1 {

    template<> struct my_traits<n2::ArrayOfBoolean> {
        static void specific(const n2::ArrayOfBoolean& v) {
            n1::generic(v.values);
        }
    };

    template<> struct my_traits<n2::ArrayOfInt> {
        static void specific(const n2::ArrayOfInt& v) {
            n1::generic(v.values);
        }
    };
}
```

---

```
c++     codec.cc   -o codec
In file included from codec.cc:1:./codec.h:17:23: error: no member named 'specific' in 'n1::my_traits<std::__1::__bit_const_reference<std::__1::vector<bool,std::__1::allocator<bool> > > >'
    my_traits<T>::specific(t);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./codec.h:26:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'n1::generic<std::__1::__bit_const_reference<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> > > >' requested here
    n1::generic(*it);
        ^
./codec.h:17:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'n1::my_traits<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> > >::specific' requested here
    my_traits<T>::specific(t);
                  ^
./codec.h:47:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'n1::generic<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> > >' requested here
    n1::generic(v.values);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This is because of the unfortunate `std::vector<bool>` specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd as it seems, a `vector<bool>` doesn't hold any `bool`s. Only bits which you cannot get a real reference to.

So in `n1::generic(*it);` there is no `const bool&`, only a `__bit_const_reference` proxy class.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool is good article vector<bool>.